# Why does Ajax.BeginForm load index again before partialview?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using Ajax.BeginForm to update a div with a partialview (loading logs based on the search input in the search fields).

The general idea is to load the Index the first time you log in with default values and then only update the log (partial view) when you search from there on.

**The problem** - When I debug my program it stops at Index in the controller before loading the partial view - resulting in long loading times.

**The question** - How can I make the Ajax request only load the partial view?

---

### Code

**_LogLayout.cshtml**

```
 <div id="log" class="tab">
     <h1>Log</h1>

     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("LogPartialView", "LogModelsController",
         new AjaxOptions
         {
             HttpMethod = "POST",
             InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
             UpdateTargetId = "divLogs",
         }, new
         {
             id = "NewTableId"
         }))
         {
             <p>@Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { @placeholder = "Message" })</p>
             if (Roles.IsUserInRole(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName, "Admin"))
             {
                 <p>
                     @Html.DropDownList("SelectedCustomer", Model.LogModelVmObject.CustomerList, new { @id = "logdropdownlabel", @class = "dropdownlabels" })
                 </p>
             }

             <p>
                 <input type="submit" class="standardbutton logsearch" name="submit" value="Search" />
             </p>
         }

         @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportData", "LogModels"))
         {
             <input type="submit" name="export" class="standardbutton export" value="Export to Excel" />
         }

         <div id="divLogs">
             @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Data)
             @Html.Partial("_LogPartialLayout")
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**LogModelsController.cs**

```
/// <returns>   
///     Returns the populated log with the current customers information if the user is of the Role Member,     
///     otherwise if the user is in the Role Admin - then show all customers logs by default.
/// </returns>
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    if (Session["myID"] == null)
        return ExpireSession();

    const int pageNumber = 1;
    var lmvm = new LogModelVm { CurrentSort = null };
    var myId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["myID"].ToString());

    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName, "Admin"))
    {
        _customer = _cdvdb.GetAllCustomerIds();
        _message = _db.GetLogs();
    }
    else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName, "Member"))
    {
        _message = _db.GetLogsById(myId);
    }

    var logs = _message.OrderByDescending(i => i.Timestamp).ToPagedList(pageNumber, PageSize);

    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName, "Admin"))
    {
        if (_customer != null)
        {
            var selectListItems = _customer as SelectListItem[] ?? _customer.ToArray();
            foreach (var log in logs)
                log.Name = selectListItems.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Value == log.CustomerId.ToString())?.Text;
            lmvm.CustomerList = selectListItems;
        }
    }

    lmvm.Logs = logs;

    var model = new LogStatisticsModel
    {
        LogModelObject = new LogModel(),
        StatisticsModel = await StatisticsData.GetAllCurrentStatisticsValues(1, DateTime.Now),
        LogModelVmObject = lmvm
    };

    return View(model);
}

/// <returns> 
///     Returns a partial view of the log. 
/// </returns>
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogPartialView(string searchString, int? selectedCustomer, string currentMessageFilter, string currentCustomerFilter, int? page, string sortOrder)
{
    // Some code.
    return PartialView("_LogPartialLayout", model);
}
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

            routes.MapRoute("Log", "{controller}/{action}/{Id}");

            routes.MapRoute("Admin", "");
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model MyProject.Models.LogStatisticsModel
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyPortal";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LogLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: The code you have shown will not hit the `Index()` method if you submit the form. Do you have nested forms?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Actually there is another form inside it for exporting data. Will update code to show this. Nothing else is nested from what I can see.

Comment: Nested forms are invalid and not supported. Your inner `Html.BeginForm("ExportData", "LogModels")` will not work correctly, but that wont cause it to hit the `Index()` method. Are you sure there is not an outer `<form>` element (or `BeginForm()` method) in your `_LogLayout.cshtml` view? And you have mentioned the `Index` view but you have not shown it. What does it contain?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry for the delay. I've added the code to Index() now and I can ensure you that there are no nested Forms in the _LogLayout.cshtml. But there are more forms - should I edit them in? (The code will be rather long if I do..).  There are 2 more BeginForms under my other tabs on the site.

Comment: I actually meant the Index view :) Does that view include any `<form>` elements? And where in that view you you generate the `_LogLayout` view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh... Well now it's added :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118297/discussion-between-danieboy-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long discussion with @StephenMuecke which (among a ton of useful things) told me to try and comment out every single javascript in the _LogLayout.cshtml file and one by one uncomment them back and see if any of them caused the problem.

I found that the following script caused the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#loadercheck').click(function () 
    {
        $('#loader').show();
        $.ajax(
        {
            success: function () 
            {
                $('#loader').delay(1200).hide(400);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

The following script was used to display a spinning loader while the log was loading data. Apparently this caused the Index() to be called again. So I will have to find a new way to display a loader now...